# jQuery drag and edit image

Tags: jquery

What jQuery plugin has the functionality to drag and edit image like Facebook? i.e, when we upload a profile image and by clicking on Edit Thumbnail, we can adjust the image part to be shown as profile picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: if you going to edit after upload try jcrop plugin http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: @Sid, I'm implementing using JCrop plugin, but unable to to it yet! I thought if there would be any other.

Comment: JCrop: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: while using jcrop what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: after dragging and adjusting the image, I'm unable to save to current state of image, isn't there any event like onSuccess etc. that would be helpful for saving the current state of image?